# getting corresponding value in the pair with the second value of the pair, in a set of pairs

Tags: c++, stl, set, c++17, std-pair

suppose I have a set of pairs in c++ as defined below :

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> s;
```

and the values stored in the set are for example :

```
s = {{"Paul", "America"}, {"Joe", "Scotland"}, {"Matt", "Russia"}};
```

I want to know how can one obtain `"America"` using only `"Paul"` in c++17

**Input** : Paul
**Output** : America

Comment: Why not [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)?

Comment: if you have a `std::set`, then there might have multiple pairs with `first == "Paul"s`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this, here are two options

1. `std::find_if` for which you'll provide function which checks only first arguments equality, but think about the case when you'll have say **(Paul, America)** and **(Paul, England)**
2. Write a wrapper for `std::pair` and overload `operator<` and `operator==`, first is for allowing to have a set of elements of that type, the second is for finding needed value, as in the first case, checking only the first one in the pair, but again, here you may go in trouble with the same case

Also using the first one you get rid of all goods `std::set` provides, because that search won't be `O(lgn)` as you may expect.

I'll recommend to use `std::map` instead, or if you can have people with same name, `std::multimap`, which btw has `equal_range` member function, which will help you to deal with that case.